# Injecting a DataContext... and there can be only one

Tags: c#, ninject

My implementation of *unit of work* and *repository* might be the root of the issue here.. but given that everywhere I look for a *unit of work* implementation I see a different one, I'm sure Ninject has a way of working around it.

So I'm injecting implementations of `IRepository<T>` into the constructor of my "unit of work".

```
_kernel.Bind<IRepository<SomeType1>>().To<RepoOfSomeType1>().WhenInjectedInto<IMyUoWFactory>();
_kernel.Bind<IRepository<SomeType2>>().To<RepoOfSomeType2>().WhenInjectedInto<IMyUoWFactory>();
...
```

I've set up the kernel to instantiate a `DataContext` in *singleton scope* which I thought would mean I'm injecting the *same instance* of this DataContext whenever I need it:

```
_kernel.Bind<DataContext>().ToConstructor(arg => new MyDataContext(arg.Inject<string>()))
                           .InSingletonScope() // pass same instance to all repositories?
                           ("connection", _someConnectionString);
```

The problem I'm finding, is that each repository seems to have its own instance, plus the unit of work has its own as well - hence the exception I'm getting when I try to commit a transaction (something about cross-context transaction).

To top it all off, in certain specific situations I need the connection string to be dynamic, so that the unit of work can work off a database that's selected by the user - hence the "need" for a factory.

The result is that I have 1 connection *per repository* plus 1 connection *per unit of work*, which defeats the purpose of UoW (i.e. transactional data operations), and all this overhead, I think, is causing serious performance issues (running +/- 200,000 small data operations in... 3-4 hours!!).

This is how I'm creating the unit of work instance; I want to be able to inject repository implementations in there, yet still be able to use the connection string that the user asked for:

```
    public MyUoWFactory(IRepository<Type1> type1repo, IRepository<Type2> type2repo,
                        IRepository<Type3> type3repo, IRepository<Type4> type4repo,
                        IRepository<Type5> type5repo, IRepository<Type6> type6repo)
    {
        _type1Repository = type1repo;
        _type2Repository = type2repo;
        _type3Repository = type3repo;
        _type4Repository = type4repo;
        _type5Repository = type5repo;
        _type6Repository = type6repo;
    }

    public IUnitOfWork Create(string userSelectedConnectionString)
    {
        return new MyUoW(new MyDataContext(userSelectedConnectionString),
                        _type1Repository, _type2Repository, _type3Repository,
                        _type4Repository, _type5Repository, _type6Repository);
    }
```

With the kernel bindings I've defined, this causes the DataContext of the repositories to point where the kernel dictates, and the DataContext of the created UoW to point where the user asked for.

How can I pull this off without resorting to *service locator*? I need the repositories to have their DataContext injected not at app start-up, but *after* the user has selected a database. Is this where `Ninject.Factory` comes into play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh.. did it again (finding answer shortly after posting in premature despair). What I wanted was the *unit of work* factory to actually *create* the repositories. So the answer is pretty simple: instead of injecting `IRepository<T>`, I created an interface `IRepositoryFactory<T>` and injected that instead:

```
public interface IRepositoryFactory<T> where T : class
{
    IRepository<T> Create(DataContext context);
}
```

This way the `Create` method of *MyUoWFactory* taking the user-selected connection string could create only one context and pass it to all repository factories:

```
public MyUoWFactory(IRepositoryFactory<Type1> type1repoFactory, IRepositoryFactory<Type2> type2repoFactory,
                    IRepositoryFactory<Type3> type3repoFactory, IRepositoryFactory<Type4> type4repoFactory,
                    IRepositoryFactory<Type5> type5repoFactory, IRepositoryFactory<Type6> type6repoFactory)
{
    _type1RepositoryFactory = type1repoFactory;
    _type2RepositoryFactory = type2repoFactory;
    _type3RepositoryFactory = type3repoFactory;
    _type4RepositoryFactory = type4repoFactory;
    _type5RepositoryFactory = type5repoFactory;
    _type6RepositoryFactory = type6repoFactory;
}

public IUnitOfWork Create(string userSelectedConnectionString)
{
    var context = new MyDataContext(userSelectedConnectionString)
    return new MyUoW(context,
                    _type1RepositoryFactory.Create(context), 
                    _type2RepositoryFactory.Create(context), 
                    _type3RepositoryFactory.Create(context),
                    _type4RepositoryFactory.Create(context), 
                    _type5RepositoryFactory.Create(context), 
                    _type6RepositoryFactory.Create(context));
}
```